# Unable to start activity in Android application while using AndroidX

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

Whenever I start activity using startActivity() I receive following logs in logcat and nothing happens on device/emulator:

```
2019-11-21 19:16:26.160 28786-28786/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.281 28786-28786/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.806 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:161)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void sphinx.com.moviemvvm.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:13)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7009)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7000)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2731)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2856)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1589)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/sphinx.com.moviemvvm--vyEhr2LbQqyK8y8nQPHbg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/sphinx.com.moviemvvm--vyEhr2LbQqyK8y8nQPHbg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2559)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.807 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.809 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.809 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
2019-11-21 19:16:26.809 28786-28786/sphinx.com.moviemvvm I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
```

I suspect this is an AndroidX lib issue as mentioned here but I am unable to resolve this using the solution provided on GitHub thread https://github.com/android/sunflower/issues/295. My App gradle files contains following code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sphinx.com.moviemvvm"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    def lifecycle_version = "2.1.0"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"

    def recyclerview_version = "1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"

    def cardview_version = "1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$cardview_version"

    //Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.2'

    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.10.0'

    //Paging
    def paging_version = "2.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"

    //RxJava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.14'

    //RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Can someone correct me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you invalidate the cache?

Comment: @Anatolii Yes I did but no success.